# Error creating an Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I've been involved with this issue since I installed Cordova Tools for VS2013 Update 4. I've been searching and trying a lot of solutions, but none of them works.

At first moment after the installation, I couldn't found the Apache Cordova Templates. Then I tried a solution from Stack Overflow and now I can see them:

[image: Available projects]

With anyone (I'm trying first with Blank App) I get always the same error message while Visual Studio creates the project:

[image: Main Error]

> The imported project 'C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Javascript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Javascript.Common.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. C:\Program Files (x86\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets

I wrote the message for someone that maybe is looking for the same error.

**Data:**

I navigated to *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Tools for Apache Cordova* and then I got this:

[image: Tools Error]

> The 'AutoLoadPackagePackage' package did not load correctly.
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'

These are the entries for that error in that file:

```
  <entry>
    <record>743</record>
    <time>2015/05/01 16:08:21.331</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [AutoLoadPackagePackage]</description>
    <guid>{E0F14200-4DD7-4F1A-8F2B-DA3B91F8E889}</guid>
    <hr>80131604</hr>
    <errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>744</record>
    <time>2015/05/01 16:08:21.369</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [AutoLoadPackagePackage]</description>
    <guid>{E0F14200-4DD7-4F1A-8F2B-DA3B91F8E889}</guid>
    <hr>80131604</hr>
    <errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I also updated Node.js. I understand there is a issue between Visual Studio and Node.js.

**References:**

[Unable to create Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831683/unable-to-create-apache-cordova-project-in-visual-studio-2013)
[Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) for Visual Studio | Can't load project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212443/cordova-multi-device-hybrid-apps-preview-for-visual-studio-cant-load-projec/24249493#24249493)
[Visual Studio/Multi Device Hybrid Apps CTP / Cordova - The imported project was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618575/visual-studio-multi-device-hybrid-apps-ctp-cordova-the-imported-project-was/25489793#25489793)
[Error when installing Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0 in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913475/error-when-installing-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp3-0-in-visual-st)
[Visual Studio Apache Cordova Build Error - cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012221/visual-studio-apache-cordova-build-error-cannot-find-module)

Comment: Currently reparing installation, if I get news I'll update

Comment: It appears that you have multiple versions of VS Cordova tools installed on your system.  Do you have VS 2015 RC installed as well?  The Ionic templates are only compatible with the Cordova tools available in VS 2015 RC.  They will not work in VS 2013.  What entries do you see in Programs and Features?  If you only have VS 2013 Update 4 installed and not VS 2015 RC, my recommendation is to uninstall everything related to Tools for Apache Cordova to get back to a known good state and then install Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1.  Or Install VS 2015 RC with the Cordova tools optional install.

Comment: Thanks I ll try it. I had nodejs and cordova from standalone before vs. Maybe that is a problem too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have multiple versions of VS Cordova tools installed. I would recommend to uninstall all the previous versions of the tools and start afresh. You can install VS 2015 RC Tools from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs). Thanks for using our tools.

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the @Ellen comment?

Comment: Not much, just that I wanted to provide a link to the install for more people running into this issue..

Comment: Thanks, but this should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks. most of the people look for answers not comments.